# JpaRepository in Repository package

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

While running my application(not yet done with it), I encountered these two errors. I have tried to figure out what they mean and how to resolve them with no success. Can someone kindly help me out. I am novice in Java. Thanks a lot.

Below you'll find my codes for Model,Repository and enums packages.

1 Error creating bean with name 'roleRepository' defined in ro.sda.finalproject.repository.RoleRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar

2 No property 'roleType' found for type 'Role'

```
package ro.sda.finalproject.model;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "role")
public class Role {
    public Role(String name) {
        super();
        this.name =name;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "role_id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;
}
```

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import ro.sda.finalproject.enums.RoleType;
import ro.sda.finalproject.model.Role;

import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.Set;

@Repository
public interface RoleRepository extends JpaRepository<Role, Long> {

    Optional<Role> findByType(RoleType type);

    // select entity join with collection
   // @Query("FROM Role r join r.users u WHERE u.id = :userId")
    Set<Role> getRoles(Long user_id);
}
```

```
package ro.sda.finalproject.enums;

public enum RoleType {
    ADMIN, CUSTOMER, USER
}
```

I tried commenting on the methods in RoleRepository and I did not receive any Error. But I believe this is not the solution to solving it.

Comment: The trace mentions something about the `@EnableJpaRepositories`. Could you share the class where said annotation is?

Comment: you didnt use RoleType in Role class

Answer (score 0):

Your query try to get Role's by type. But you're not define role type in role object.Your role object must be similar like this:

```
public class Role {
    public Role(String name) {
        super();
        this.name =name;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "role_id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;
    
    @Column(name="roleType")
    private RoleType roleType; 

}
```